# compare the information between two matrices R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices, one is generated out of the other by deleting some rows. For example:

```
m = matrix(1:18, 6, 3)
m1 = m[c(-1, -3, -6),]
```

Suppose I do not know which rows in m were eliminated to create m1, how should I find it out by comparing the two matrices? The result I want looks like this:

```
1, 3, 6
```

The actual matrix I am dealing with is very big. I was wondering if there is any efficient way of conducting it.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some approaches:

**1)** If we can assume that there are no duplicated rows in `m` -- this is the case in the example in the question -- then:

```
which(tail(!duplicated(rbind(m1, m)), nrow(m)))
## [1] 1 3 6
```

**2)** Transpose `m` and `m1` giving `tm` and `tm1` since it is more efficient to work on columns than rows.

Define `match_indexes(i)` which returns a vector r such that each row in `m[r, ]` matches `m1[i, ]`.

Apply that to each i in 1:n1 and remove the result from 1:n.

```
n <- nrow(m); n1 <- nrow(m1)
tm <- t(m); tm1 <- t(m1)

match_indexes <- function(i) which(colSums(tm1[, i] == tm) == n1)
setdiff(1:n, unlist(lapply(1:n1, match_indexes)))
## [1] 1 3 6
```

**3)**  Calculate an interaction vector for each matrix and then use `setdiff` and finally `match` to get the indexes:

```
i <- interaction(as.data.frame(m))
i1 <- interaction(as.data.frame(m1))
match(setdiff(i, i1), i)
## [1] 1 3 6
```

**Added** If there can be duplicates in `m` then (1) and (3) will only return the first of any multiply occurring row in `m` not in `m1`.

```
m <- matrix(1:18, 6, 3)
m1 <- m[c(2, 4, 5),]
m <- rbind(m, m[1:2, ])
# 1
which(tail(!duplicated(rbind(m1, m)), nrow(m)))
## 1 3 6

# 2
n <- nrow(m); n1 <- nrow(m1)
tm <- t(m); tm1 <- t(m1)
match_indexes <- function(i) which(colSums(tm1[, i] == tm) == n1)
setdiff(1:n, unlist(lapply(1:n1, match_indexes)))
## 1 3 6 7

# 3
i <- interaction(as.data.frame(m))
i1 <- interaction(as.data.frame(m1))
match(setdiff(i, i1), i)
## 1 3 6
```

Comment: I prefer the first one. It is also faster. See benchmark in my answer.

Comment: The first one is great. But unfortunately my m matrix itself has duplicated rows. Still, I like the novel approach you presented here. Thanks!

Comment: Actually we can relax the condition a bit..  It is OK if there are duplicated rows in m if they are also in m1.  If there are duplicated rows in m that are not in m1 then only the first of each multply occuring rows will be included in the output vector.  Is that  good enough?

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to represent each row as a string:

```
x1 <- apply(m, 1, paste0, collapse = ';')
x2 <- apply(m1, 1, paste0, collapse = ';')
which(!x1 %in% x2)
# [1] 1 3 6
```

Some benchmark with a large matrix using my solution and [G. Grothendieck's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403312/3926543):

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(20000 * 5000), nrow = 20000)
m1 <- m[-sample.int(20000, 1000), ]

system.time({
    which(tail(!duplicated(rbind(m1, m)), nrow(m)))
})
#    user  system elapsed
# 339.888   2.368 342.204
system.time({
    x1 <- apply(m, 1, paste0, collapse = ';')
    x2 <- apply(m1, 1, paste0, collapse = ';')
    which(!x1 %in% x2)
})
#    user  system elapsed
# 395.428   0.568 395.955

system({
    n <- nrow(m); n1 <- nrow(m1)
    tm <- t(m); tm1 <- t(m1)

    match_indexes <- function(i) which(colSums(tm1[, i] == tm) == n1)
    setdiff(1:n, unlist(lapply(1:n1, match_indexes)))
})
# > 15 min, not finish


system({
    i <- interaction(as.data.frame(m))
    i1 <- interaction(as.data.frame(m1))
    match(setdiff(i, i1), i)
})
# run out of memory. My 32G RAM machine crashed.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But my matrix m is actually a document-term matrix of 14290 rows and 4413 terms. Could this method handle such a big matrix?

Comment: @user7453767, this one is very slow on that large matrix. I made a test example and ran it several min ago. It is not finished yet.

Comment: This Is very helpful! Thank you @mt1022

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `do.call`

```
which(!do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m)) %in% do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m1)))
#[1] 1 3 6
```